# Convert Timestamp to ISO Format after Form Submission

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

Newbie question here and I'm not sure if this is best practice but:

I'm looking to convert a timestamp pulled in from a form submission and change it to ISO.  For display reasons, I'd like to keep the time option displayed to the user like: `Sept 30th 2017 11am EST`.  I'm looking to change this into `2017-09-30T11:00:00Z`.  I'm also trying to get this dynamic so if it is `Oct 22nd 2017 10am EST` it would result in `2017-10-22T10:00:00Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the (3rd party) [`dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/) module to help with parsing the incoming time value:

```
from dateutil import parser

ts = parser.parse('Sept 30th 2017 11am EST')
print(ts.isoformat())

print(parser.parse('Oct 22nd 2017 10am EST').isoformat())
```

Output:

```
2017-09-30T11:00:00
2017-10-22T10:00:00
```

This does lose the timezone, however, assuming EST is UTC-5:

```
>>> print(parser.parse('Sept 30th 2017 11am EST', tzinfos={'EST': -(5*3600)}))
2017-09-30 11:00:00-05:00
>>> print(parser.parse('Oct 22nd 2017 10am EST', tzinfos={'EST': -(5*3600)}))
2017-10-22 10:00:00-05:00
```

Comment: @Rem: there is a `tzinfos` argument that you can pass to `parse()` which is a dictionary mapping timezone names to offsets.